# Flex client disconecting

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I am using BlazeDS. Does anybody know how to disconnect client from server? Client must be informed about this event.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew BlazeDS does not support open connections between the Flash Player and the server.  You'll have to use LiveCycle if you want to do that.

When you make a server call using the HTTPService, WebService, or RemoteObject tags, there are events that fire when you receive feedback from the server, such as result or fault.  When those events fire, you can safely assume that that service call is no longer connected ot the server.